# Nginx Geoip redirect subdomain

Tags: nginx, redirect, geoip

i try to redirect a user from DE to a subdomain https://de.example.com when he enters main domain https://www.example.com.

I tried the following:

```
if ($geoip_country_code ~ (DE)) {
return 301 https://de.example.com$request_uri;

if ($host = 'example.com') {
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

The country redirect is working but conflicts with the other redirect.
How to combine them both?

**(Update)**

and when i do it like this..

```
map $geoip_city_country_code $closest_server {
    default www.example.com;
    DE      de.example.com;
}

if ($closest_server != $host) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$closest_server$request_uri break;
}
```

then its all working! BUT non DE is restricted to www.example.com and cant browse for example to ar.example.com, he.example.com etc etc, which is poison for the google bot. So if there is a wildcard value for **default** it would be perfect.

**(Update)**

well,

i tried it now like this:
**nginx.conf:**

```
map $geoip_city_country_code $allowed_country {
    default 0;
    DE 1;
}
```

**hostfile:**

```
server {
    if ($allowed_country = 1) {
        return 301 $scheme://de.example.com$request_uri;
    }
...
```

But if visit now the default domain i get a redirect to de.example.com but an error:

There were too many redirections.

> Error Code: INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED

Comment: In what way do they conflict?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'll be appreciated if you can share. Thank you.